# Failed to Export Multiple components in React

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to render `list` in `index.js`, where the todo list items appear. I tried to export from `CreateArea.jsx` both the `CreateArea` and `todoItems` (an array). Here's what I've done:

```
function listItems(value) {
    var todoItems = [defaultItem];
    const defaultItem = "Welcome to the Todo-List App!"
    todoItems.push(value);
}

function CreateArea() {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    function onClick() {
        listItems(inputRef.current.value);
        console.log("Pushed item in the array!");
    }

    return (
        <div className="mainbox">
            <div className="inputdiv">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref={inputRef} // tell the input element to use this ref.
                  placeholder="Enter Task..."
                  className="textbox"
                  id="taskName"
                />
                <button className="button" onClick={onClick}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export {CreateArea, todoItems};
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
Error - Failed to compile.

./src/components/CreateArea.jsx
SyntaxError: C:\Users\huang\Desktop\WebApps\React-Todo-List\my-app\src\components\CreateArea.jsx: Export 'todoItems' is not defined. (35:20)

  33 | }
  34 |
  35 | export {CreateArea, todoItems};
     |                     ^
  36 |
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: please share your error log (edit your post and then add the error log). your error log tells you on which line you use todoItem, then think about todoItem definition and exportation.

Comment: thank you for the edition. your problem is that you create and define todoItems inside a function. so todoItem is only available inside of ListItem. so you cannot export it. you can read more about javascript lexical scope.

Answer (score 1):

There's no todoItems defined inside index.js. The `todoItems` variable is defined under `listItem`, so its value is not available during export.

Also, you're adding `defaultItem` to `todoItem` array before even declaring it. This will also throw error.